# Compiling multiple programs with Makefile

Tags: shell, unix, cuda, makefile, mpi

I have to compile three separate program using 4 different cpp files and including one cuda file.

Files are:

```
final_serial.cpp
final_mpi.cpp
final_mpicuda.cpp and final_cuda.cu
```

The final_mpicuda.cpp and final_cuda.cu must link together.

My current Makefile, just to compile the first two files, serial and mpi, looks like this:

```
MPIDIR=/usr/lib64/mpich2/
CC=$(MPIDIR)/bin/mpic++
LIBS=-L$(MPIDIR)/lib -lmpl -lopa

all: serial mpi

mpi: final_mpi.cpp
    $(CC) $(LIBS) -o $@ $^

serial: final_serial.cpp
    g++ -o serial final_serial.cpp
```

The think is, in order to link `final_mpicuda.cpp` and `final_cuda.cu` together, I have to do these commands:

```
/usr/local/cuda-5.0/bin/nvcc --compiler-bindir /usr/local/gcc/bin -c final_cuda.cu -o cudacode.o
/usr/lib64/mpich2/bin/mpic++ -lmpl -lopa -c final_mpicuda.cpp -o mpicode.o
/usr/lib64/mpich2/bin/mpic++ -lmpl -lopa mpicode.o cudacode.o -L/usr/local/cuda-5.0/lib64 -lcudart -o cuda
```

Which produces an executable named `cuda`. So, my question is, how can I produce a file called `cuda` with using the Makefile mentioned above. I don't know how to incorporate the three commands for linking these files together into the Makefile.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
mpicode.o: final_mpicuda.cpp
    $(CC) -lmpl -lopa -c $< -o $@

cudacode.o: final_cuda.cu
    /usr/local/cuda-5.0/bin/nvcc --compiler-bindir /usr/local/gcc/bin -c $< -o $@

cuda: mpicode.o cudacode.o
    $(CC) -lmpl -lopa $^ -L/usr/local/cuda-5.0/lib64 -lcudart -o $@
```

Comment: I am getting an error that says "*** missing separator.  Stop."

Comment: @FidelCashflo: on which line?

Comment: @FidelCashflo - you need to use tabs for the recipes.

Comment: I am using tabs. and it is on line 14, $(CC) -lmpl -lopa -c $< -o $@
, I simply copied what you posted into my current Makefile.

Comment: Actually, I got it working. It was an error with the tabbing. Sorry about that. Thank you for your help!